# How to massively restore all file edits from eclipse history?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, revision-history

I'm in a lot of trouble.
During a composer update, somehow, the git process crashes and I have lost all my edits since last commit. It looks like there was an hard reset of my repository.

In eclipse I can find all the history files but I have to iterate on every file to check if it was changed and get the last version.
Unfortunately the massive "restore from local history" on the project doesn't work for edited file but only for deleted.
Is there any way to browse eclipse history and get all the last versions?
I know there are inside .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history but they are hashed and probably I have many version of the same file.